# Find the planes that are farthest from the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Among all the planes that are tangent to the surface $xy^2z^2=1$, find the ones that are farthest from the origin.

So far I have $\nabla f=(y^2z^2,2xyz^2,2xy^2z)$, and I know if I were to find the tangent plane at the point $(a,b,c)$, the equation is $b^2c^2(x-a)+2abc^2(y-b)+2ab^2c(z-c)$. How would I go from here?

Comment: What whave you tried?

Comment: I've tried finding the general equation for the tangent planes so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distance from a point to a plane is given by $d =|\vec{QP} \cdot n|/\|n\|$. Here we can let $Q = (0,0,0)$ and $P$ be any point on the plane. Now take an arbitrary point $P = \left(\frac{1}{y^2z^2},y,z\right)$ on the surface. The normal vector at this point if $\nabla f(P) = \left\langle y^2z^2,\frac{2}{y},\frac{2}{z}\right\rangle$. Now we have that the distance;

$$d = d(y,z) = \frac{5}{\sqrt{y^4z^4+\frac{4}{y^2}+\frac{4}{z^2}}}$$

Now find the max and min values, assuming you are constrained to a ball of radius $\|\vec{OP}\|$.